# Java string triangle

Tags: java, string

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DrawTriangle
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a height");
    while (!scan.hasNextInt()) // while non-integers are present
    {
        scan.next();
        System.out.println ("Bad input. Enter an integer.");
    }
    int input = scan.nextInt();
    for (int x = 1; x <= input; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < input; y++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");

            for (int z = 1; z < y; z++)
            {
                System.out.print("x");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

}

I have to make a triangle of x's relating to the height specified by the user. Can't get it to work at all, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Sorry should have clarified
I need it to look like this -

```
   x
  xxx
 xxxxx
```

Comment: Oh no, not again. It's homeworks season, it seems! I don't even want to bother to find the duplicates.

Comment: @ppeterka It's **always** the season for triangle questions. They really deserve a tag of their own, together with a snippet in the tag wiki that solves all of them.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik and I bet, even then, at least weekly once, we had this question pop up no matter what happens...

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik. How about you getting the job of creating all those possible questions and solutions? lol ;)

Comment: @ppeterka That's what I like about the idea of the tag wiki: just slap it onto the question, and you've answered it :)

Comment: @RohitJain Yeah, that's kind of the idea behind this tag wiki :) I mean, how hard can it be, rectangular, equilateral, upside-down, with x's or asterisks, ... not much more there.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik.. `not much more there` - uhmm :-|

Comment: @RohitJain It's supposed to be a... **learning** experience. The teachers already trust their students to have mastered the skills of C-c and C-v.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik : The sad thing that they are too lazy to do the old thing: 1: search for solution on google, 2:C-c, 3:C-v. The first step got left out from the process. (I did teach at high level... Significant amount of students were too lazy or too dumb to find the answer to questions hidden in the text of the other questions... This is sad...)

Comment: @ppeterka I used to teach Java and it was too frustrating for me, I just quit. But I'd place the main issue to utter disinterest. You can't make a disinterested student learn.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik.. Exactly. My 100 cents to your last comments. I have also seen this problem, when I was teaching few months back in a college.

Comment: @RohitJain it's interesting that with three totally different places, totally different people (and quite some of them), but  the same problem is very much the same. I thought my issue was due to local causes, and has always hoped that it is better elsewhere...

Comment: @ppeterka.. Lol.. I think its very rare to get better crowd in schools or colleges. Everyone start becoming serious once entering Corporate World.

Comment: Just want to add, this is 'homework' however I learn by seeing the code in front of me and working through it. We're on a tight deadline regarding getting practicals done, so I can either get loads done on time and get a better mark, or sit around teaching myself Java whilst not getting these practicals done on time. Once the deadline is past, I can then spend sometime properly learning some of this stuff!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need nested loop upto 3 levels. Just `2 levels` are needed. `One` for traversing along `columns`,  and `one` for traversing along `rows`.

So, change your loop to: -

```
    for (int x = 1; x <= input; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < x; y++)
        {
            System.out.print("x ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

**UPDATE : -**

For equilateral triangle, you would need to add one more loop to print spaces before `x` on the starting rows. Here's the code: -

```
    for (int x = 1; x <= input; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < input - x; y++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < x; y++) {
            System.out.print("x ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry should have clarified, it should look like an Equilateral triangle, sorry for the vague description.

Comment: @user155478.. Will edit the code. You would need two loops then.

Comment: i know its tempting to write such easy code, but being homework i think a hint in the right direction would be more helpful in the long run. (And will keep this site from becoming "do my homework dot com"). Just my two cents.

Comment: @jambriz.. Yeah, sure. And my first two lines was intended for that purpose only. And I added modified code only. Of course, code should not be added if OP has not tried anything. But given that he has posted some code he tried, we can modify it to work correctly, of course with an explanation.