# Output is not printing as expected

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I have my code for this task mostly done, just can't figure out what is causing the the output to be incorrect. The desired output when using say, 3 and A for the values, should return this:

> > A
>
> AA

AAA

currently, I'm getting:

AAA

AAA

AAA

code:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class TriangleThree
{
private int size;
private String letter;

public TriangleThree()
{
}

public TriangleThree(int count, String let)
{
    size = count;
    letter = let;
}

public void setTriangle( String let, int sz )
{
    size = sz;
    letter = let;
}

public String getLetter()
{
    return letter;
}

public String toString()
{
    String output="";
    for(int i = 1; i<=size; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j > i;j++ )
        {
            output = output + " ";
        }
        
        for(int k = size; k>0; k--)
        {
            output = output + letter;
        }
        output= output + "\n";
    }
        
    
    
    
    
    return output+"\n";
}
}
```

and for cross-referencing it with my runner class:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab11c
{
public static void main( String args[] )
{
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice="";
        do{
            out.print("Enter the size of the triangle : ");
            int big = keyboard.nextInt();
            out.print("Enter a letter : ");
            String value = keyboard.next();

                //instantiate a TriangleThree object
         TriangleThree tt = new TriangleThree( big, value );
            //call the toString method to print the triangle
            System.out.println( tt );

            System.out.print("Do you want to enter more data? ");
            choice=keyboard.next();
        }while(choice.equals("Y")||choice.equals("y"));
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running your 2nd for loop 3 times (All from `size` to `0`). Change it to: -

```
    for(int k = i; k>0; k--)
    {
        output = output + letter;
    }
```

This will run `1 time` for `i = 1`, `2 times` for `i = 2`, ...

Also, there is a problem with your first loop: -

```
for(int j = 0; j > i;j++ )
```

this should really be: -

```
for(int j = 0; j < i;j++ )
```

---

**UPDATE : -**

Actually you don't need your first loop, as it is just printing spaces. Rather add spaces to your `output` in the 2nd loop only: -

```
    for(int k = i; k>0; k--)
    {
        output = output + letter + " ";
    }
```

Comment: so maybe try `for(int k = 0; k <= size; k++)
              {
                 output = output + letter;
              }`

Comment: @tech_geek23.. Yeah that would also work. Will not make much of a difference.

Comment: ok, your re-written code seems to be doing the trick, I'm still getting 3 A's, in this case, on each line after the spaces

Comment: I'm still getting it like this
> A

>  AA

>   AAA

it needs to be more like:


>  A

> AA

>AAA

Comment: @tech_geek23.. Can't understand. What do you get the output now?

Comment: as in, it's adding more spaces each time it prints out the next line when there should only be, in this case, 3 "slots" for either a space or letter

Comment: @tech_geek23.. That's because you are running a loop for spaces also.

Comment: @tech_geek23.. See my update. You can remove the loop which is printing spaces.

Comment: it just seems like it's adding way too many there should be only 2 spaces followed by a single a in line one, then one space followed by 2 A's in line two, and finally no spaces followed by 3 A's in line three. The the 3rd "column" should line up throughout the 3 lines

Comment: @tech_geek23.. Hey.. Did you just asked the same question a few hours ago with the title `Java String Triangle`?

Comment: I adjusted my OP to include a more proper format for the output, I didn't realize it didn't include the spaces *before* the letter(s) and now have the spaces represented

Comment: I did not ask the same question a few hours ago, it's actually been several days since I've gotten on StackOverflow

Comment: @tech_geek23.. Oh, then you can see this post: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519597/java-string-triangle/13519620#13519620 where I answered a similar question. You can use the for loop I posted there in your `toString` method.

Comment: modded the code there slightly and got it to function properly! thanks and happy Thanksgiving (if you're in the US)!